# How can I know if `git gc --auto` has done something?

Tags: git, git-gc, git-maintenance

I'm running `git gc --auto` as part of an automatic saves script. I'd like to run further cleanup if `git gc --auto` has done something, but I'd like to spare the hassle if `git gc --auto` doesn't feel like something need to be done. Is there a way to check the return value of `git gc --auto`, or to check beforehand if it is necessary to run it ?

Comment: The short answer is "no". The longer answer is: what exactly would you do? Whatever you would do (check reflog counts?) you can do that and see if they have changed. It's hard to wait for an automatic GC in the first place though; you would want an explicit, non-automatic GC just so you can tell when it's done.

Comment: I guess the real problem is I'm using git with very very very large repositories, and sometimes `git gc --auto` fails (disk space, or oomkiller) and leaves stuff that can be disposed of with `git pack-redundant --all | xargs rm`, that nicely fill up the disk. I guess I can run `git pack-redundant` sytematically ?

Comment: Ah. Ideally, you'd want to monitor the failures (I'm not sure if Linux has the right kind of process tracing to do that), but otherwise you could indeed just do an occasional pack-redundant check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), "[`git maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/52b8c8c7165987650bf873b878f20b14c33b268f/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance))</sup> , the extended big brother of "[`git gc`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/52b8c8c7165987650bf873b878f20b14c33b268f/Documentation/git-gc.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc))</sup> presented in [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64077241/6309), continues to evolve.

It is more precise than `git gc` and the options introduced in 2.30 allow to know when it has done something, as asked in the OP.

See [commit e841a79](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e841a79a131d8ce491cf04d0ca3e24f139a10b82), [commit a13e3d0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a13e3d0ec87c9d12b93700375fceacdfb2c6885f), [commit 52fe41f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/52fe41ff1cd6e1f0b67d4e864e718d949e225f30), [commit efdd2f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/efdd2f0d4c4d6b1b1090171b6428919038bd2980), [commit 18e449f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/18e449f86b74bab35b150549c8342d252fe7ae00), [commit 3e220e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e220e60696ebc27c719b83adc6f734d6857521f), [commit 252cfb7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/252cfb7cb86a33f7740c799748ee6c586931c7bc), [commit 28cb5e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/28cb5e66ddaed47aa8789fa326fec0339831b80b) (25 Sep 2020) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 52b8c8c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/52b8c8c7165987650bf873b878f20b14c33b268f), 27 Oct 2020)</sup>

> ### [`maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/52fe41ff1cd6e1f0b67d4e864e718d949e225f30): add incremental-repack task
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> The previous change cleaned up loose objects using the 'loose-objects' that can be run safely in the background. Add a similar job that performs similar cleanups for pack-files.
>
> One issue with running '[`git repack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/52fe41ff1cd6e1f0b67d4e864e718d949e225f30/Documentation/git-repack.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack))</sup> ' is that it is designed to repack all pack-files into a single pack-file. While this is the most space-efficient way to store object data, it is not time or memory efficient. This becomes extremely important if the repo is so large that a user struggles to store two copies of the pack on their disk.
>
> Instead, perform an "incremental" repack by collecting a few small pack-files into a new pack-file. The multi-pack-index facilitates this process ever since '[`git multi-pack-index expire`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/52fe41ff1cd6e1f0b67d4e864e718d949e225f30/Documentation/git-multi-pack-index.txt#L38)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-multi-pack-index#Documentation/git-multi-pack-index.txt-expire))</sup> ' was added in [19575c7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/19575c7c8e60c95c6714e51039ee9a21721cc31d) ("`multi-pack-index`: implement 'expire' subcommand", 2019-06-10, Git v2.23.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4308d81d456c8c3ecc2c33af7f4d834de95130b9) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c9b961d7eb15fb583a2a812088713a68a85f1c0)) and '[`git multi-pack-index repack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/52fe41ff1cd6e1f0b67d4e864e718d949e225f30/Documentation/git-multi-pack-index.txt#L43)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-multi-pack-index#Documentation/git-multi-pack-index.txt-repack))</sup> ' was added in [ce1e4a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce1e4a105b4ff2457f2537bc703863175f9195c9) ("`midx`: implement `midx_repack()`", 2019-06-10, Git v2.23.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4308d81d456c8c3ecc2c33af7f4d834de95130b9) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c9b961d7eb15fb583a2a812088713a68a85f1c0)).
>
> The 'incremental-repack' task runs the following steps:
>
> 1. '[`git multi-pack-index write`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/52fe41ff1cd6e1f0b67d4e864e718d949e225f30/Documentation/git-multi-pack-index.txt#L32)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-multi-pack-index#Documentation/git-multi-pack-index.txt-write))</sup>' creates a multi-pack-index file if one did not exist, and otherwise will update the multi-pack-index
>    with any new pack-files that appeared since the last write. This
>    is particularly relevant with the background fetch job.
>
>    When the multi-pack-index sees two copies of the same object, it
>    stores the offset data into the newer pack-file. This means that
>    some old pack-files could become "unreferenced" which I will use
>    to mean "a pack-file that is in the pack-file list of the
>    multi-pack-index but none of the objects in the multi-pack-index
>    reference a location inside that pack-file."
> 2. '[`git multi-pack-index expire`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/52fe41ff1cd6e1f0b67d4e864e718d949e225f30/Documentation/git-multi-pack-index.txt#L38)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-multi-pack-index#Documentation/git-multi-pack-index.txt-expire))</sup>' deletes any unreferenced pack-files and updates the multi-pack-index to drop those pack-files from the
>    list. This is safe to do as concurrent Git processes will see the
>    multi-pack-index and not open those packs when looking for object
>    contents. (Similar to the 'loose-objects' job, there are some Git
>    commands that open pack-files regardless of the multi-pack-index,
>    but they are rarely used. Further, a user that self-selects to
>    use background operations would likely refrain from using those
>    commands.)
> 3. '[`git multi-pack-index repack --bacth-size=<size>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/52fe41ff1cd6e1f0b67d4e864e718d949e225f30/Documentation/git-multi-pack-index.txt#L43)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-multi-pack-index#Documentation/git-multi-pack-index.txt-repack))</sup>' collects a set of pack-files that are listed in the multi-pack-index and creates
>    a new pack-file containing the objects whose offsets are listed
>    by the multi-pack-index to be in those objects. The set of pack-
>    files is selected greedily by sorting the pack-files by modified
>    time and adding a pack-file to the set if its "expected size" is
>    smaller than the batch size until the total expected size of the
>    selected pack-files is at least the batch size. The "expected
>    size" is calculated by taking the size of the pack-file divided
>    by the number of objects in the pack-file and multiplied by the
>    number of objects from the multi-pack-index with offset in that
>    pack-file. The expected size approximates how much data from that
>    pack-file will contribute to the resulting pack-file size. The
>    intention is that the resulting pack-file will be close in size
>    to the provided batch size.
>
>    The next run of the incremental-repack task will delete these
>    repacked pack-files during the 'expire' step.
>
>    In this version, the batch size is set to "0" which ignores the
>    size restrictions when selecting the pack-files. It instead
>    selects all pack-files and repacks all packed objects into a
>    single pack-file. This will be updated in the next change, but
>    it requires doing some calculations that are better isolated to
>    a separate change.
>
> These steps are based on a similar background maintenance step in [Scalar (and VFS for Git)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64077241/6309). This was incredibly effective for users of the Windows OS repository.
> After using the same VFS for Git repository for over a year, some users had *thousands* of pack-files that combined to up to 250 GB of data. We noticed a few users were running into the open file descriptor limits (due in part to a bug in the multi-pack-index fixed by [af96fe3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/af96fe3392fb078cb5447bcb94f2ed8d79d0a4a8) ("`midx`: add packs to `packed_git` linked list", 2019-04-29, Git v2.22.0-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/454b419729142cd65466cabdb253d06c3699d098)).
>
> These pack-files were mostly small since they contained the commits and trees that were pushed to the origin in a given hour. The GVFS protocol includes a "prefetch" step that asks for pre-computed pack-files containing commits and trees by timestamp. These pack-files were grouped into "daily" pack-files once a day for up to 30 days. If a user did not request prefetch packs for over 30 days, then they would get the entire history of commits and trees in a new, large pack-file. This led to a large number of pack-files that had poor delta compression.
>
> By running this pack-file maintenance step once per day, these repos with thousands of packs spanning 200+ GB dropped to dozens of pack- files spanning 30-50 GB. This was done all without removing objects from the system and using a constant batch size of two gigabytes. Once the work was done to reduce the pack-files to small sizes, the batch size of two gigabytes means that not every run triggers a repack operation, so the following run will not expire a pack-file. This has kept these repos in a "clean" state.

`git maintenance` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/52fe41ff1cd6e1f0b67d4e864e718d949e225f30/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L88-L105):

> ### `incremental-repack`
>
> The `incremental-repack` job repacks the object directory
> using the `multi-pack-index` feature. In order to prevent race
> conditions with concurrent Git commands, it follows a two-step
> process. First, it calls `git multi-pack-index expire` to delete
> pack-files unreferenced by the `multi-pack-index` file. Second, it
> calls `git multi-pack-index repack` to select several small
> pack-files and repack them into a bigger one, and then update the
> `multi-pack-index` entries that refer to the small pack-files to
> refer to the new pack-file. This prepares those small pack-files
> for deletion upon the next run of `git multi-pack-index expire`.
> The selection of the small pack-files is such that the expected
> size of the big pack-file is at least the batch size; see the
> `--batch-size` option for the `repack` subcommand in
> [`git multi-pack-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-multi-pack-index). The default batch-size is zero,
> which is a special case that attempts to repack all pack-files
> into a single pack-file.

And:

> ### [`maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e841a79a131d8ce491cf04d0ca3e24f139a10b82): add incremental-repack auto condition
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> The incremental-repack task updates the multi-pack-index by deleting pack-files that have been replaced with new packs, then repacking a batch of small pack-files into a larger pack-file. This incremental repack is faster than rewriting all object data, but is slower than some other maintenance activities.
>
> The '`maintenance.incremental-repack.auto`' config option specifies how many pack-files should exist outside of the multi-pack-index before running the step.
> These pack-files could be created by '[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e841a79a131d8ce491cf04d0ca3e24f139a10b82/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup>' commands or by the loose-objects task.
> The default value is 10.
>
> Setting the option to zero disables the task with the '`--auto`' option, and a negative value makes the task run every time.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e841a79a131d8ce491cf04d0ca3e24f139a10b82/Documentation/config/maintenance.txt#L26-L34):

> ### `maintenance.incremental-repack.auto`
>
> This integer config option controls how often the `incremental-repack`
> task should be run as part of `git maintenance run --auto`. If zero,
> then the `incremental-repack` task will not run with the `--auto`
> option. A negative value will force the task to run every time.
> Otherwise, a positive value implies the command should run when the
> number of pack-files not in the multi-pack-index is at least the value
> of `maintenance.incremental-repack.auto`. The default value is 10.

---

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), adds parts of "[`git maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7660da161821ab79b8ecd5019c28843ed7e770a6/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance))</sup> to ease writing crontab entries (and other scheduling system configuration) for it.

See [commit 0016b61](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0016b618182f642771dc589cf0090289f9fe1b4f), [commit 61f7a38](https://github.com/git/git/commit/61f7a383d3b9a7306f1fd44a8dfa070deacc0752), [commit a4cb1a2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a4cb1a2339c1aa4ba71ebc6d2b07d537e1071124) (15 Oct 2020), [commit 2fec604](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2fec604f8df51fcf47551723e68a3447915b9eb9), [commit 0c18b70](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c18b700810ab2e2a4fac0d5b54a817141198a27), [commit 4950b2a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4950b2a2b5c4731e4c9d5b803739a6979b23fed6), [commit b08ff1f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b08ff1fee000230ad22fee823aabff2613bd4e62) (11 Sep 2020), and [commit 1942d48](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1942d48380fec53f76361e9adebef15b5db9628a) (28 Aug 2020) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7660da1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7660da161821ab79b8ecd5019c28843ed7e770a6), 18 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0016b618182f642771dc589cf0090289f9fe1b4f): add troubleshooting guide to docs
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> The '[`git maintenance run`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0016b618182f642771dc589cf0090289f9fe1b4f/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L58)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance#Documentation/git-maintenance.txt-run))</sup> ' subcommand takes a lock on the object database to prevent concurrent processes from competing for resources. This is an important safety measure to prevent possible repository corruption and data loss.
>
> This feature can lead to confusing behavior if a user is not aware of it. Add a TROUBLESHOOTING section to the '[`git maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0016b618182f642771dc589cf0090289f9fe1b4f/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance))</sup> ' builtin documentation that discusses these tradeoffs.
>
> The short version of this section is that Git will not corrupt your repository, but if the list of scheduled tasks takes longer than an hour then some scheduled tasks may be dropped due to this object database collision.
> For example, a long-running "daily" task at midnight might prevent an "hourly" task from running at 1AM.
>
> The opposite is also possible, but less likely as long as the "hourly" tasks are much faster than the "daily" and "weekly" tasks.

`git maintenance` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0016b618182f642771dc589cf0090289f9fe1b4f/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L178-L221):

> TROUBLESHOOTING
>
> ---
>
> The `git maintenance` command is designed to simplify the repository
> maintenance patterns while minimizing user wait time during Git commands.
> A variety of configuration options are available to allow customizing this
> process. The default maintenance options focus on operations that complete
> quickly, even on large repositories.
>
> Users may find some cases where scheduled maintenance tasks do not run as
> frequently as intended. Each `git maintenance run` command takes a lock on
> the repository's object database, and this prevents other concurrent
> `git maintenance run` commands from running on the same repository. Without
> this safeguard, competing processes could leave the repository in an
> unpredictable state.
>
> The background maintenance schedule runs `git maintenance run` processes
> on an hourly basis. Each run executes the "hourly" tasks. At midnight,
> that process also executes the "daily" tasks. At midnight on the first day
> of the week, that process also executes the "weekly" tasks. A single
> process iterates over each registered repository, performing the scheduled
> tasks for that frequency. Depending on the number of registered
> repositories and their sizes, this process may take longer than an hour.
> In this case, multiple `git maintenance run` commands may run on the same
> repository at the same time, colliding on the object database lock. This
> results in one of the two tasks not running.
>
> If you find that some maintenance windows are taking longer than one hour
> to complete, then consider reducing the complexity of your maintenance
> tasks. For example, the `gc` task is much slower than the
> `incremental-repack` task. However, this comes at a cost of a slightly
> larger object database. Consider moving more expensive tasks to be run
> less frequently.
>
> Expert users may consider scheduling their own maintenance tasks using a
> different schedule than is available through `git maintenance start` and
> Git configuration options. These users should be aware of the object
> database lock and how concurrent `git maintenance run` commands behave.
> Further, the `git gc` command should not be combined with
> `git maintenance run` commands. `git gc` modifies the object database
> but does not take the lock in the same way as `git maintenance run`. If
> possible, use `git maintenance run --task=gc` instead of `git gc`.

Comment: Wow... Exactly what I needed. It looks like I'll have to switch to recent versions of git !

Comment: @VonC: Default confirm for MIDX files since Git 2.34 (Q4 2021)
See [commit 0d0d8d8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d0d8d8a11f85d563552a7e91129814e315d9c78) (24 Sep 2021) by [Eric Wong (`ele828`)](https://github.com/ele828).  

Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b39b0e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b39b0e1a829fc085c779f39f53d974b619494f8a), 06 Oct 2021)

Answer (score 16):

Update Sept. 2020: you won't have to run only `git gc --auto` as part of your automatic saves script.

The old "`gc`" can now be superseded by the new `git maintenance run --auto`.
And it can display what it is doing.

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), A "[`git gc`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/48794acc50f14394ca6c4f5092a4a498f409f350/Documentation/git-gc.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc))</sup>'s big brother has been introduced to **take care of more repository maintenance tasks**, not limited to the object database cleaning.

See [commit 25914c4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25914c4fdeefd99b06e134496dfb9bbb58a5c417), [commit 4ddc79b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ddc79b2dac18189e7ff18e99a6fabdd161f866c), [commit 916d062](https://github.com/git/git/commit/916d0626c202c18e6d615abb69ba1f15b335c3ea), [commit 65d655b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/65d655b52df3d4db0b4980f60106ed9785d025f8), [commit d7514f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d7514f6ed57d20bcc9dcfb43016b95dba82ba790), [commit 090511b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/090511bc0b73bf3054f11df6f275ad3a3abbf34f), [commit 663b2b1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/663b2b1b90bf76275044824ddeca96aaec240f09), [commit 3103e98](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3103e9848f7b7534eac14c0521d7b49b32466b70), [commit a95ce12](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a95ce124305adcc4980241b8877e06db1d6ed411), [commit 3ddaad0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ddaad0e06035a752c9010dcd5094b37262080fb), [commit 2057d75](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2057d75038541cd16debb1c55f3f897fd244965c) (17 Sep 2020) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 48794ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48794acc50f14394ca6c4f5092a4a498f409f350), 25 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2057d75038541cd16debb1c55f3f897fd244965c): create basic maintenance runner
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Jonathan Nieder</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> The 'gc' builtin is our current entrypoint for automatically maintaining a repository. This one tool does many operations, such as:
>
> - repacking the repository,
> - packing refs, and
> - rewriting the commit-graph file.
>
> The name implies it performs "garbage collection" which means several different things, and some users may not want to use this operation that rewrites the entire object database.
>
> Create a new '**`maintenance`**' builtin that will become a more general- purpose command.
>
> To start, it will only support the '`run`' subcommand, but will later expand to add subcommands for scheduling maintenance in the background.
>
> For now, the '`maintenance`' builtin is a thin shim over the '`gc`' builtin.
> In fact, the only option is the '`--auto`' toggle, which is handed directly to the '`gc`' builtin.
> The current change is isolated to this simple operation to prevent more interesting logic from being lost in all of the boilerplate of adding a new builtin.
>
> Use existing [`builtin/gc.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2057d75038541cd16debb1c55f3f897fd244965c/builtin/gc.c) file because we want to share code between the two builtins.
> It is possible that we will have '`maintenance`' replace the '`gc`' builtin entirely at some point, leaving '[`git gc`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2057d75038541cd16debb1c55f3f897fd244965c/Documentation/git-gc.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc))</sup>' as an alias for some specific arguments to '`git maintenance run`'.
>
> Create a new `test_subcommand` helper that allows us to test if a certain subcommand was run. It requires storing the `GIT_TRACE2_EVENT` logs in a file.
> A negation mode is available that will be used in later tests.

(That last part is one way to ascertain the new `git maintainance run --auto` does something)

`git maintenance` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2057d75038541cd16debb1c55f3f897fd244965c/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L1-L57):

> ## git-maintenance(1)
>
> ### NAME
>
> `git-maintenance` - Run tasks to optimize Git repository data
>
> ### SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> [verse]
> 'git maintenance' run [<options>]
> ```
>
> ### DESCRIPTION
>
> Run tasks to optimize Git repository data, speeding up other Git commands
> and reducing storage requirements for the repository.
>
> Git commands that add repository data, such as `git add` or `git fetch`,
> are optimized for a responsive user experience. These commands do not take
> time to optimize the Git data, since such optimizations scale with the full
> size of the repository while these user commands each perform a relatively
> small action.
>
> The `git maintenance` command provides flexibility for how to optimize the
> Git repository.
>
> ### SUBCOMMANDS
>
> #### `run`
>
> Run one or more maintenance tasks.
>
> ### TASKS
>
> #### `gc`
>
> Clean up unnecessary files and optimize the local repository. "GC"
> stands for "garbage collection," but this task performs many
> smaller tasks. This task can be expensive for large repositories,
> as it repacks all Git objects into a single pack-file. It can also
> be disruptive in some situations, as it deletes stale data. See
> [`git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) for more details on garbage collection in Git.
>
> ### OPTIONS
>
> #### `--auto`
>
> When combined with the `run` subcommand, run maintenance tasks
> only if certain thresholds are met. For example, the `gc` task
> runs when the number of loose objects exceeds the number stored
> in the `gc.auto` config setting, or when the number of pack-files
> exceeds the `gc.autoPackLimit` config setting.

---

> ### [`maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a95ce124305adcc4980241b8877e06db1d6ed411): replace `run_auto_gc()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> The `run_auto_gc()` method is used in several places to trigger a check for repo maintenance after some Git commands, such as '[`git commit`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a95ce124305adcc4980241b8877e06db1d6ed411/Documentation/git-commit.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit))</sup> or '[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a95ce124305adcc4980241b8877e06db1d6ed411/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup>.
>
> To allow for extra customization of this maintenance activity, replace the '[`git gc --auto [--quiet]`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a95ce124305adcc4980241b8877e06db1d6ed411/Documentation/git-gc.txt#L44)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc#Documentation/git-gc.txt---auto))</sup>' call with one to '[`git maintenance run --auto [--quiet]`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a95ce124305adcc4980241b8877e06db1d6ed411/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L48)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance#Documentation/git-maintenance.txt---auto))</sup>'.
> As we extend the maintenance builtin with other steps, users will be able to select different maintenance activities.
>
> Rename `run_auto_gc()` to `run_auto_maintenance()` to be clearer what is happening on this call, and to expose all callers in the current diff. Rewrite the method to use a struct `child_process` to simplify the calls slightly.
>
> Since '[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a95ce124305adcc4980241b8877e06db1d6ed411/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> already allows disabling the '[`git gc --auto`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a95ce124305adcc4980241b8877e06db1d6ed411/Documentation/git-gc.txt#L44)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc#Documentation/git-gc.txt---auto))</sup> subprocess, add an equivalent option with a different name to be more descriptive of the new behavior: '`--[no-]maintenance`'.

`fetch-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a95ce124305adcc4980241b8877e06db1d6ed411/Documentation/fetch-options.txt#L100-L102):

> Run `git maintenance run --auto` at the end to perform automatic
> repository maintenance if needed. (`--[no-]auto-gc` is a synonym.)
> This is enabled by default.

`git clone` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a95ce124305adcc4980241b8877e06db1d6ed411/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L81-L83):

> which automatically call `git maintenance run --auto`. (See
> [`git maintenance`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance).)

---

Plus, your save script will be able to make `git maintenance` do more than `git gc` ever could, thanks to **tasks**.

> ### [`maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/090511bc0b73bf3054f11df6f275ad3a3abbf34f): add --task option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> A user may want to only run certain maintenance tasks in a certain order.
>
> Add the `--task=<task>` option, which allows a user to specify an ordered list of tasks to run. These cannot be run multiple times, however.
>
> Here is where our array of `maintenance_task` pointers becomes critical. We can sort the array of pointers based on the task order, but we do not want to move the struct data itself in order to preserve the hashmap references. We use the hashmap to match the --task= arguments into the task struct data.
>
> Keep in mind that the '`enabled`' member of the `maintenance_task` struct is a placeholder for a future '`maintenance.<task>.enabled`' config option. Thus, we use the '`enabled`' member to specify which tasks are run when the user does not specify any `--task=<task>` arguments.
> The '`enabled`' member should be ignored if `--task=<task>` appears.

`git maintenance` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/090511bc0b73bf3054f11df6f275ad3a3abbf34f/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L33-L35):

> Run one or more maintenance tasks. If one or more `--task=<task>`
> options are specified, then those tasks are run in the provided
> order. Otherwise, only the `gc` task is run.

`git maintenance` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/090511bc0b73bf3054f11df6f275ad3a3abbf34f/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L33-L35):

> ### `--task=<task>`
>
> If this option is specified one or more times, then only run the
> specified tasks in the specified order. See the 'TASKS' section
> for the list of accepted `<task>` values.

And:

> ### [`maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/65d655b52df3d4db0b4980f60106ed9785d025f8): create maintenance..enabled config
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> Currently, a normal run of "[`git maintenance run`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/65d655b52df3d4db0b4980f60106ed9785d025f8/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L32)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance#Documentation/git-maintenance.txt-run))</sup> will only run the '`gc`' task, as it is the only one enabled.
> This is mostly for backwards-compatible reasons since "[`git maintenance run --auto`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/65d655b52df3d4db0b4980f60106ed9785d025f8/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L60)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance#Documentation/git-maintenance.txt---auto))</sup> commands replaced previous "`git gc --auto`" commands after some Git processes.
>
> Users could manually run specific maintenance tasks by calling "`git maintenance run --task=<task>`" directly.
>
> Allow users to customize which steps are run automatically using config. The '`maintenance.<task>.enabled`' option then can turn on these other tasks (or turn off the '`gc`' task).

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/65d655b52df3d4db0b4980f60106ed9785d025f8/Documentation/config/maintenance.txt#L1-L6):

> ### `maintenance.<task>.enabled`
>
> This boolean config option controls whether the maintenance task
> with name `<task>` is run when no `--task` option is specified to
> `git maintenance run`. These config values are ignored if a
> `--task` option exists.
> By default, only `maintenance.gc.enabled` is true.

`git maintenance` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/65d655b52df3d4db0b4980f60106ed9785d025f8/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L33-L37):

> Run one or more maintenance tasks. If one or more `--task` options
> are specified, then those tasks are run in that order. Otherwise,
> the tasks are determined by which `maintenance.<task>.enabled`
> config options are true.
> By default, only `maintenance.gc.enabled` is true.

`git maintenance` now also includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/65d655b52df3d4db0b4980f60106ed9785d025f8/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L33-L37):

> If no `--task=<task>`
> arguments are specified, then only the tasks with
> `maintenance.<task>.enabled` configured as `true` are considered.

---

Another way to know if the new `git maintenance run` is doing currently anything is to check for a lock (`.git/maintenance.lock` file):

> ### [`maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d7514f6ed57d20bcc9dcfb43016b95dba82ba790): take a lock on the objects directory
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> Performing maintenance on a Git repository involves writing data to the `.git` directory, which is not safe to do with multiple writers attempting the same operation.
> Ensure that only one '[`git maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d7514f6ed57d20bcc9dcfb43016b95dba82ba790/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance))</sup> process is running at a time by holding a file-based lock.
>
> Simply the presence of the `.git/maintenance.lock` file will prevent future maintenance. This lock is never committed, since it does not represent meaningful data. Instead, it is only a placeholder.
>
> If the lock file already exists, then no maintenance tasks are attempted. This will become very important later when we implement the '`prefetch`' task, as this is our stop-gap from creating a recursive process loop between '[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d7514f6ed57d20bcc9dcfb43016b95dba82ba790/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> ' and '[`git maintenance run --auto`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d7514f6ed57d20bcc9dcfb43016b95dba82ba790/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L58)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance#Documentation/git-maintenance.txt---auto))</sup>.

---

You can also check if `git gc`/`git maintenance` *will* have to do anything.

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), A "[`git gc`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/48794acc50f14394ca6c4f5092a4a498f409f350/Documentation/git-gc.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc))</sup> 's big brother has been introduced to take care of more repository maintenance tasks, not limited to the object database cleaning.

See [commit 25914c4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25914c4fdeefd99b06e134496dfb9bbb58a5c417), [commit 4ddc79b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ddc79b2dac18189e7ff18e99a6fabdd161f866c), [commit 916d062](https://github.com/git/git/commit/916d0626c202c18e6d615abb69ba1f15b335c3ea), [commit 65d655b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/65d655b52df3d4db0b4980f60106ed9785d025f8), [commit d7514f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d7514f6ed57d20bcc9dcfb43016b95dba82ba790), [commit 090511b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/090511bc0b73bf3054f11df6f275ad3a3abbf34f), [commit 663b2b1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/663b2b1b90bf76275044824ddeca96aaec240f09), [commit 3103e98](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3103e9848f7b7534eac14c0521d7b49b32466b70), [commit a95ce12](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a95ce124305adcc4980241b8877e06db1d6ed411), [commit 3ddaad0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ddaad0e06035a752c9010dcd5094b37262080fb), [commit 2057d75](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2057d75038541cd16debb1c55f3f897fd244965c) (17 Sep 2020) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 48794ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48794acc50f14394ca6c4f5092a4a498f409f350), 25 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/916d0626c202c18e6d615abb69ba1f15b335c3ea): use pointers to check `--auto`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> The '[`git maintenance run`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/916d0626c202c18e6d615abb69ba1f15b335c3ea/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L32)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance#Documentation/git-maintenance.txt-run))</sup> ' command has an '--auto' option. This is used by other Git commands such as '[`git commit`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/916d0626c202c18e6d615abb69ba1f15b335c3ea/Documentation/git-commit.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit))</sup> ' or '[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/916d0626c202c18e6d615abb69ba1f15b335c3ea/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> ' to check if maintenance should be run after adding data to the repository.
>
> Previously, this `--auto` option was only used to add the argument to the '[`git gc`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/916d0626c202c18e6d615abb69ba1f15b335c3ea/Documentation/git-gc.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc))</sup> command as part of the '`gc`' task.
> We will be expanding the other tasks to perform a check to see if they should do work as part of the `--auto` flag, when they are enabled by config.
>
> - First, update the 'gc' task to perform the auto check inside the maintenance process.
>   This prevents running an extra '[`git gc --auto`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/916d0626c202c18e6d615abb69ba1f15b335c3ea/Documentation/git-gc.txt#L44)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc#Documentation/git-gc.txt---auto))</sup> command when not needed.
>   It also shows a model for other tasks.
> - Second, use the '`auto_condition`' function pointer as a signal for whether we enable the maintenance task under '`--auto`'.
>   For instance, we do not want to enable the 'fetch' task in '`--auto`' mode, so that function pointer will remain `NULL`.
>
> We continue to pass the '--auto' option to the '[`git gc`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/916d0626c202c18e6d615abb69ba1f15b335c3ea/Documentation/git-gc.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc))</sup> command when necessary, because of the `gc.autoDetach` config option changes behavior.
> Likely, we will want to absorb the daemonizing behavior implied by `gc.autoDetach` as a `maintenance.autoDetach` config option.

---

To illustrate what `git maintenance` will do that `git gc` won't:

> ### [`maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/663b2b1b90bf76275044824ddeca96aaec240f09): add commit-graph task
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> The first new task in the '[`git maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/663b2b1b90bf76275044824ddeca96aaec240f09/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance))</sup> ' builtin is the '`commit-graph`' task.
> This updates the commit-graph file incrementally with the command
>
> ```
> git commit-graph write --reachable --split
> ```
>
> By writing an incremental commit-graph file using the "`--split`" option we minimize the disruption from this operation.
>
> The default behavior is to merge layers until the new "top" layer is less than half the size of the layer below. This provides quick writes most of the time, with the longer writes following a power law distribution.
>
> Most importantly, concurrent Git processes only look at the commit-graph-chain file for a very short amount of time, so they will very likely not be holding a handle to the file when we try to replace it. (This only matters on Windows.)
>
> If a concurrent process reads the old commit-graph-chain file, but our job expires some of the `.graph` files before they can be read, then those processes will see a warning message (but not fail). This could be avoided by a future update to use the `--expire-time` argument when writing the commit-graph.

`git maintenance` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/663b2b1b90bf76275044824ddeca96aaec240f09/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L38-L45):

> ### `commit-graph`
>
> The `commit-graph` job updates the `commit-graph` files incrementally,
> then verifies that the written data is correct.
>
> The incremental
> write is safe to run alongside concurrent Git processes since it
> will not expire `.graph` files that were in the previous
> `commit-graph-chain` file. They will be deleted by a later run based
> on the expiration delay.

And:

> ### [`maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ddc79b2dac18189e7ff18e99a6fabdd161f866c): add auto condition for `commit-graph` task
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> Instead of writing a new `commit-graph` in every '[`git maintenance run --auto`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4ddc79b2dac18189e7ff18e99a6fabdd161f866c/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L60)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance#Documentation/git-maintenance.txt---auto))</sup> process (when `maintenance.commit-graph.enabled` is configured to be `true`), only write when there are "enough" commits not in a `commit-graph` file.
>
> This count is controlled by the `maintenance.commit-graph.auto` config option.
>
> To compute the count, use a depth-first search starting at each ref, and leaving markers using the `SEEN` flag.
> If this count reaches the limit, then terminate early and start the task.
> Otherwise, this operation will peel every ref and parse the commit it points to. If these are all in the `commit-graph`, then this is typically a very fast operation.
>
> Users with many refs might feel a slow-down, and hence could consider updating their limit to be very small. A negative value will force the step to run every time.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4ddc79b2dac18189e7ff18e99a6fabdd161f866c/Documentation/config/maintenance.txt#L7-L16):

> ### `maintenance.commit-graph.auto`
>
> This integer config option controls how often the `commit-graph` task
> should be run as part of `git maintenance run --auto`.
>
> - If zero, then the `commit-graph` task will not run with the `--auto` option.
> - A negative value will force the task to run every time.
> - Otherwise, a positive value implies the command should run when the number of
>   reachable commits that are not in the commit-graph file is at least
>   the value of `maintenance.commit-graph.auto`.
>
> The default value is 100.

---

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), the test-coverage enhancement of running `commit-graph` task "[`git maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0be2d65132d6b75b2146c28eb024568afa242739/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance))</sup> as needed led to discovery and fix of a bug.

See [commit d334107](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d334107c5da27e5212e21e77da03e938ea6db976) (12 Oct 2020), and [commit 8f80180](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f801804befa12a9c4ddff91275cf03612f1895d) (08 Oct 2020) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0be2d65](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0be2d65132d6b75b2146c28eb024568afa242739), 02 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f801804befa12a9c4ddff91275cf03612f1895d): test commit-graph auto condition
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> The auto condition for the `commit-graph` maintenance task walks refs looking for commits that are not in the `commit-graph` file.
> This was added in [4ddc79b2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ddc79b2dac18189e7ff18e99a6fabdd161f866c) ("`maintenance`: add auto condition for commit-graph task", 2020-09-17, Git v2.29.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48794acc50f14394ca6c4f5092a4a498f409f350) listed in [batch #17](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9bc233ae1cf19a49e51842c7959d80a675dbd1c0)) but was left untested.
>
> The initial goal of this change was to demonstrate the feature works properly by adding tests. However, there was an off-by-one error that caused the basic tests around `maintenance.commit-graph.auto=1` to fail when it should work.
>
> The subtlety is that if a ref tip is not in the `commit-graph`, then we were not adding that to the total count. In the test, we see that we have only added one commit since our last commit-graph write, so the auto condition would say there is nothing to do.
>
> The fix is simple: add the check for the `commit-graph` position to see that the tip is not in the `commit-graph` file before starting our walk. Since this happens before adding to the DFS stack, we do not need to clear our (currently empty) commit list.
>
> This does add some extra complexity for the test, because we also want to verify that the walk along the parents actually does some work. This means we need to add at least two commits in a row without writing the `commit-graph`. However, we also need to make sure no additional refs are pointing to the middle of this list or else the `for_each_ref()` in `should_write_commit_graph()` might visit these commits as tips instead of doing a DFS walk. Hence, the last two commits are added with "[`git commit`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8f801804befa12a9c4ddff91275cf03612f1895d/Documentation/git-commit.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit))</sup> instead of `"test_commit"`.

---

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), "[`git maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f2a75cb312d775c51c2029bcce227e3ea078c5f8/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance))</sup> run/start/stop" needed to be run in a repository to hold the lockfile they use, but didn't make sure they are actually in a repository, which has been corrected.

See [commit 0a1f2d0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0a1f2d05d202f40f62e749c87dfeb0970e865171) (08 Dec 2020) by [Josh Steadmon (`steadmon`)](https://github.com/steadmon).
See [commit e72f7de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e72f7defc4f454cc7ad512d9a16a78b83f2606d8) (26 Nov 2020) by [Rafael Silva (`raffs`)](https://github.com/raffs).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f2a75cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f2a75cb312d775c51c2029bcce227e3ea078c5f8), 08 Dec 2020)</sup>

> ### [`maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e72f7defc4f454cc7ad512d9a16a78b83f2606d8): fix SEGFAULT when no repository
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Rafael Silva</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> The "[`git maintenance run git`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e72f7defc4f454cc7ad512d9a16a78b83f2606d8/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L58)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance#Documentation/git-maintenance.txt-run))</sup> and "`git maintenance start/stop`" commands holds a file-based lock at the `.git/maintenance.lock` and `.git/schedule.lock` respectively.
> These locks are used to ensure only one maintenance process is executed at the time as both operations involves writing data into the repository.
>
> The path to the lock file is built using `"`the_repository->objects->odb->path" `` that results in SEGFAULT when we have no repository available as `"`the_repository->objects->odb" `` is set to `NULL`.
>
> Let's teach maintenance command to use `RUN_SETUP` option that will provide the validation and fail when running outside of a repository. Hence fixing the SEGFAULT for all three operations and making the behaviour consistent across all subcommands.
>
> Setting the `RUN_SETUP` also provides the same protection for all subcommands given that the "register" and "unregister" also requires to be executed inside a repository.
>
> Furthermore let's remove the local validation implemented by the "register" and "unregister" as this will not be required anymore with the new option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are monitoring `git gc --auto` exit status (for detecting a failure for instance), that return value has changed with Git 2.20:

See [commit 3029970](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3029970275b473dbf62149887a19a6b4879528d7) (17 Jul 2018) by [Jonathan Nieder (`artagnon`)](https://github.com/artagnon).
Helped-by: [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 993fa56](https://github.com/git/git/commit/993fa5625876306ff1de0cbc5d70fc1b232568b9), 16 Oct 2018)</sup>

> ### `gc`: exit with status 128 on failure
>
> A value of `-1` returned from `cmd_gc gets` propagated to `exit()`, resulting in an exit status of 255.
> Use die instead for a clearer error message and a controlled exit.

Instead of "`error: The last gc run reported the following.`", you now have:

```
fatal: The last gc run reported the following
```