# Why git bash installed in windows runs scripts in background?

Tags: windows, git, bash

I am using git bash in windows to run some nodejs scripts but whenever I use it and exit git bash automatically shifts that process to background and doesn't let me use that port until unless I kill that port using command.

But when I use cmd it works perfectly and process doesn't run in background and there no need to kill process running on port any answer why?

Comment: This issue might be resolved soon. see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 2):

That is also reported in [vscode issue 24452](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24452) leading to [node-pty issue 7](https://github.com/Tyriar/node-pty/issues/7).

Both refer to [git-for-windows/git issue 227](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/227)

The official maintainer [Johannes Schindelin (dscho)](https://github.com/dscho) mentions 3 months ago (June 2017):

> Alas, it is not. In v2.13.1, I changed the way Ctrl+C works and the problem described in this ticket still persists.
>
> Any help would be very much appreciated.

[ConEmu/issue 402](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/402#issuecomment-193816182) includes:

> The problem comes from different implementations of Ctrl+C processing in cygwin/msys applications.
> POSIX applications are ready to process "[signals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal)" in most cases, but often ignores [console events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683242.aspx).

---

Update April 2018, [Johanes just added](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/227#issuecomment-383473585):

> After testing this with my fix for [#1491](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1491) (which will hit https://wingit.blob.core.windows.net/files/index.html soon, so you can verify my claim, and you should, if you are interested in this issue) it would appear that there is no longer a freeze (although quite a bit of delay if you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> tons of times).

See [git-for-windows/MSYS2-packages commit f4fda0f](https://github.com/git-for-windows/MSYS2-packages/commit/f4fda0f30aa04eb296128f11841dd4198e4e90ed):

> ### `msys2-runtime`: revamp <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> handling yet again

> This thing again...
>
> Background: when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on Linux or macOS, a signal (`SIGINT`) is
> sent to the foreground process and its child processes. This signal can
> be intercepted by installing a signal handler for this specific signal.
> On Windows, there is no precise equivalent for this system.
>
> Instead, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is translated by the current ConHost (i.e. the
> container running the Console processes) to a `ConsoleCtrl` event that is
> sent to all processes attached to that Console. If any of these
> processes installed a handler via `SetConsoleCtrlHandler()`, they can
> intercept that event (and avoid exiting or doing some cleanup work).
>
> On Linux and macOS (and every Unix flavor, really), processes can also
> be killed via the `kill` executable, which really just sends a signal to
> the process, typically `SIGTERM`. Processes can intercept that signal,
> too. To force processes to terminate, without giving them any chance to
> prevent that, `SIGKILL` can be sent.
> There is no equivalent for `SIGTERM` on
> Windows. To emulate `SIGKILL` on Windows, `TerminateProcess()` can be used,
> but it only kills one process (unlike `SIGKILL`, which is sent also to the
> child processes).
>
> In Git for Windows, we struggled with emulating `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM` and
> `SIGKILL` handling essentially since the beginning of the efforts to port
> Git to Windows.

The rest of the comment describes the original attempt and the new one.

That might go into Git 2.18 (Q2 2018).

---

Another cause for background job with Git for Windows: the new command [`git maintenance`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64077241/6309) (Git 2.29 (Q4 2020)).

But that changes with Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), and the introduction of the **scheduled maintenance tasks** to support platforms whose native scheduling methods are not 'cron'.

See [commit 3797a0a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3797a0a7b7aa8d0abd1b7ff7b95a40a9739d9278), [commit 2afe7e3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2afe7e35672dabd6e0e10165abbf6cbdf59d865b) (05 Jan 2021), and [commit 16c5690](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16c56909298a3d0639e4bc5f22760ecd75eefb5b), [commit 31345d5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/31345d5545e755bf79143841f3840ae5bcd0ac0b) (24 Nov 2020) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b2ace18](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2ace18759c4a103eecb3f5f86a098f53c71fe01), 15 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3797a0a7b7aa8d0abd1b7ff7b95a40a9739d9278): use Windows scheduled tasks
>
> <sup>Co-authored-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> Git's background maintenance uses cron by default, but this is not available on Windows.
> Instead, integrate with Task Scheduler.
>
> Tasks can be scheduled using the 'schtasks' command.
> There are several command-line options that can allow for some advanced scheduling, but unfortunately these seem to all require authenticating using a password.
>
> Instead, use the "`/xml`" option to pass an XML file that contains the configuration for the necessary schedule.
> These XML files are based on some that I exported after constructing a schedule in the Task Scheduler GUI.
> These options only run background maintenance when the user is logged in, and more fields are populated with the current username and SID at run-time by 'schtasks'.
>
> Since the `GIT_TEST_MAINT_SCHEDULER` environment variable allows us to specify 'schtasks' as the scheduler, we can test the Windows-specific logic on other platforms.
> Thus, add a check that the XML file written by Git is valid when xmllint exists on the system.
>
> Since we use a temporary file for the XML files sent to '`schtasks`', we prefix the random characters with the frequency so it is easier to examine the proper file during tests.
> Instead of an exact match on the '`args`' file, we '`grep`' for the arguments other than the filename.
>
> There is a deficiency in the current design.
> Windows has two kinds of applications: GUI applications that start by "`winmain()`" and console applications that start by "`main()`".
> Console applications are attached to a new Console window if they are not already associated with a GUI application.
> This means that every hour the scheduled task launches a command window for the scheduled tasks.
> Not only is this visually obtrusive, but it also takes focus from whatever else the user is doing!
>
> A simple fix would be to insert a GUI application that acts as a shim between the scheduled task and Git.
> This is currently possible in Git for Windows by setting the `<Command>` tag equal to
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe
> ```
>
> with options "`--hide --no-needs-console --command=cmd\git.exe`", followed by the arguments currently used.
> Since `git-bash.exe` is not included in Windows builds of core Git, I chose to leave out this feature.
> My plan is to submit a small patch to Git for Windows that converts the use of `git.exe` with this use of `git-bash.exe` in the short term.
> In the long term, we can consider creating this GUI shim application within core Git, perhaps in `contrib/`.

`git maintenance` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3797a0a7b7aa8d0abd1b7ff7b95a40a9739d9278/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L316-L337):

> ### BACKGROUND MAINTENANCE ON WINDOWS SYSTEMS
>
> Windows does not support `cron` and instead has its own system for
> scheduling background tasks. The `git maintenance start` command uses
> the `schtasks` command to submit tasks to this system. You can inspect
> all background tasks using the Task Scheduler application. The tasks
> added by Git have names of the form `Git Maintenance (<frequency>)`.
> The Task Scheduler GUI has ways to inspect these tasks, but you can also
> export the tasks to XML files and view the details there.
>
> Note that since Git is a console application, these background tasks
> create a console window visible to the current user. This can be changed
> manually by selecting the "Run whether user is logged in or not" option
> in Task Scheduler. This change requires a password input, which is why
> `git maintenance start` does not select it by default.
>
> If you want to customize the background tasks, please rename the tasks
> so future calls to `git maintenance (start|stop)` do not overwrite your
> custom tasks.

Comment: Also semi-related: https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinMsys.html#Problems_with_cygwin