# Will Git ever clone, fetch, or push orphan commits?

Tags: git, git-push, git-clone, git-fetch, orphan

Orphan commits are created when there is no tag or branch that contains them in its graph of parent commits.  For example, if you make a branch `foo`, add commits `a` and `b`, then delete the branch (i.e. remove the reference `foo` from commit `b`), then both `a` and `b` will not be reachable unless you saved their hashes.

```
x-x-x-x   <- master
     \
      a-b  <- foo (reference then deleted or reset to somewhere on master)
```

Basic Git behavior on orphaned commits is to eventually garbage collect and delete them (I have heard the default is at least 30 days).

#### My question is this:

**Will Git ever move orphan commits from one repo to another using the `git clone`, `git fetch`, or `git push` commands?**

Or does Git effectively ignore these commits for any operation that does not directly call out an orphan's hash (such as `checkout` or `cherry-pick`)?

Comment: At least it will when you clone a repository on the local machine. For example, `git clone ~/foo.git -- ~/bar`. If the remote repository is on another server, it will not. But not sure. I guess it depends on the protocol.

Comment: @ElpieKay is correct, it really depends on the underlying transfer protocol. If the sending Git chooses (for whatever reason) to send the objects inside a pack, the receiving Git gets them, and has to repack the pack to drop them. As a general rule, though, anything that gathers objects by starting from names won't gather those objects and hence won't send them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

During normal Git workflow, those commits are ignored. This includes `git clone`, `git push`, and `git fetch`.  But depending on the Git repo hosting server, you might be able to pull them back in your repo, if that is needed.

That is what I described in "[Does github remember commit IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958418/6309)": through the [GitHub  Event API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/), you can get back the SHA1 of a (for instance) deleted branch, and restore it that way in your own repo.

That compensates for the fact a [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) is generally not accessible/public on the remote side.

Comment: Thanks - but I'm not really _trying_ to pull them down, just trying to establish the behavior so I understand.  There are cases where you might want orphan commits to just die and not be transmitted anywhere, and other cases where you might want to try to revive them.

Comment: I understand. They are not transferred, unless, as I illustrate in the answer, you actively seek to reference them.

Comment: I edited your answer - please verify I understood correctly in my rewording.  In the end it appears that there are some tricks to be able to find a commit that ends up orphaned on a remote, and you can always use reflog for this on a local, but in general orphaned commits are not transferred between repos with normal git commands, with or without special flags.

Comment: Is there a way to delete an orphaned commit from a remote (say, Bitbucket)? I have managed to create one somehow using an initial commit and subsequent push of an existing project to that repository.

Comment: @MadPhysicist To be really sure an orphaned commit is deleted on the remote server side, I would contact the Git repositories hosting service support (here BitBucket support: https://support.atlassian.com/contact) and request for said commit to be deleted (probably through a `git gc` or the [more recent `git maintenance`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64077241/6309))

Comment: @VonC, wow. How did I end up in such a mess? :-) I simply created a new repo and was trying to move an existing project there using `git push --all`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Is that orphan commit problematic in any way? Usually, it should be ignored.

Comment: @VonC, nah, it is not problematic. Just a bit of an eye-sore when scrolling through the commits section. Is there a chance that it'll get garbage-collected automatically by the Bitbucket?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, but the occurrences are not fixed or predictable, as illustrated by https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-to-trigger-git-gc-on-the-server/qaq-p/1144439. Or https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-11593