# what is .git folder in mac os ?

Tags: git, macos

so i've installed git into my computer long time ago but recently noticed i'm out of space and theres folder called .git which takes almost 18GB Storage. when exploring the folder i found some meaningless weird files don't know where that came from. I'm thinking to delete it but a bit worry if its important for my mac or some file system. if any one has this file please let me know about its purpose so i can decide what to do with it.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It (the `.git/` directory) is the directory used by [git](http://git-scm.com/) for all its data and meta-data.

If you remove it, you won't be able to use `git` anymore on that particular source tree.

You should try first to run [`git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc).

I'm surprised you have such a huge `.git`.  Perhaps you have unwillingly `git add`-ed some executable or some other rather big binary file which often changes. You'll better use `git` *only* for [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code). You might consider having some `.gitignore` file and at least `git rm` large binary files.

Comment: However, it's (in my eyes) strange, that you have created a git repository in your home folder. Was this on purpose? or have you maybe created it accidentally on that level?

Comment: im sure i did not make that huge repository but was shocked when i notice it at first

Answer (score 0):

Warning: `git gc` is now (2021) replaced with [`git maintenance`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64077241/6309) ([man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance)), and running it on MacOs can fail (which means your huge .git folder would not be cleaned up)

With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), "[`git maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4293c057dcc8a8806d158a4c1f27deca34245558/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance))</sup> scheduler fix for macOS.

See [commit a16eb6b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a16eb6b1ff333f3e26b99f17ef3bb7dbf8135f39) (24 Aug 2021) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
See [commit bb01122](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb01122a82002dc5948147800da40a149779a7b1) (24 Aug 2021) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4293c05](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4293c057dcc8a8806d158a4c1f27deca34245558), 08 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a16eb6b1ff333f3e26b99f17ef3bb7dbf8135f39): skip bootout/bootstrap when plist is registered
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> On macOS, we use `launchctl` to manage the background maintenance schedule.
> This uses a set of `.plist` files to describe the schedule, but these files are also registered with '`launchctl bootstrap`'.
>
> If multiple '[`git maintenance start`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a16eb6b1ff333f3e26b99f17ef3bb7dbf8135f39/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L65)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance#Documentation/git-maintenance.txt-start))</sup> commands run concurrently, then they can collide replacing these schedule files and registering them with `launchctl`.
>
> To avoid extra `launchctl` commands, do a check for the `.plist` files on disk and check if they are registered using '`launchctl list <name>`'.
> This command will return with exit code 0 if it exists, or exit code 113 if it does not.
>
> We can test this behavior using the `GIT_TEST_MAINT_SCHEDULER` environment variable.

```
GIT_TEST_MAINT_SCHEDULER=launchctl:./print-args git maintenance start
```