# How to check status of bare repo in git

Tags: git, git-bare, git-status, git-gc

I have a bare repo cloned and need to check if the repo is broken. I tried running `git status`, but it says:

```
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree.
```

I have also tried running `git gc` and it returns non-zero if the repo is broken. But this takes hell of a time as repo size is big.

Any alternate approach in doing this?

Update: I have tried `git fsck`, and this also takes more or less same time as `git gc`. The repo size is almost ~16 gb :(

Comment: if by "checking the repo" you mean you want to check that all commits have valid parents, and a valid content, then I am afraid you will have to pay the cost to dig through those 16GB -- hence the time taken by `git gc` or `git fsck`. Do you have a suitable smaller scope in mind ?

Answer (score 2):

With a [recent enough Git (2.30+)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64077241/6309), you can also try a [`git maintenance command`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance).

Specifically: `git maintenance start`

If it starts successfully, the repository is not broken.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [`git fsck`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck):

```
git fsck --verbose --full --strict
```