# Why does "git prune --expire=never" run so long?

Tags: git

I've set `gc.pruneExpire = never` in my repo configuration. When I run `git remote update`, I see this process stack:

```
git remote update
`-git fetch --multiple --all
  `-git maintenance run --auto --no-quiet
    `-git gc --auto --no-quiet
      `-git prune --expire never
```

... and `git prune` runs for several minutes. I'm wondering what it does, as pruning is effectively switched off in this repo.

`GIT_TRACE2` log snippet:

```
16:06:15.068020 run-command.c:738                 child_start[3] git prune --expire never
16:06:15.069992 common-main.c:48                  version 2.33.0
16:06:15.070006 common-main.c:49                  start /usr/libexec/git/git prune --expire never
16:06:15.070180 git.c:456                         cmd_name prune (remote/fetch/maintenance/gc/prune)
16:07:10.501223 git.c:714                         exit elapsed:55.431555 code:0
16:07:10.501263 trace2/tr2_tgt_normal.c:123       atexit elapsed:55.431631 code:0
16:07:10.684134 run-command.c:993                 child_exit[3] pid:4658 code:0 elapsed:55.616096
```

You can see that it ran for >50s.

Update 2021-09-10: `GIT_TRACE2_PERF` output:

```
10:08:10.599900 common-main.c:48             | d3 | main                     | version      |     |           |           |              | 2.33.0
10:08:10.599927 common-main.c:49             | d3 | main                     | start        |     |  0.000411 |           |              | /usr/libexec/git/git gc --auto
 --no-quiet
10:08:10.600125 git.c:456                    | d3 | main                     | cmd_name     |     |           |           |              | gc (remote/fetch/maintenance/g
c)
...
10:08:31.766606 run-command.c:738            | d3 | main                     | child_start  |     | 21.167084 |           |              | [ch3] class:? argv:[git prune 
--expire never]
10:08:31.768137 common-main.c:48             | d4 | main                     | version      |     |           |           |              | 2.33.0
10:08:31.768154 common-main.c:49             | d4 | main                     | start        |     |  0.000395 |           |              | /usr/libexec/git/git prune --e
xpire never
10:08:31.768353 git.c:456                    | d4 | main                     | cmd_name     |     |           |           |              | prune (remote/fetch/maintenanc
e/gc/prune)
10:08:31.768473 progress.c:268               | d4 | main                     | region_enter | r0  |  0.000714 |           | progress     | label:Checking connectivity
10:08:31.768488 read-cache.c:2370            | d4 | main                     | region_enter | r0  |  0.000732 |           | index        | ..label:do_read_index ./index
10:08:31.768503 read-cache.c:2375            | d4 | main                     | region_leave | r0  |  0.000747 |  0.000015 | index        | ..label:do_read_index ./index
10:09:26.402642 progress.c:328               | d4 | main                     | data         | r0  | 54.634883 | 54.634169 | progress     | ..total_objects:0
10:09:26.402710 progress.c:336               | d4 | main                     | region_leave | r0  | 54.634953 | 54.634239 | progress     | label:Checking connectivity
10:09:26.578281 git.c:714                    | d4 | main                     | exit         |     | 54.810499 |           |              | code:0
10:09:26.578331 trace2/tr2_tgt_perf.c:213    | d4 | main                     | atexit       |     | 54.810558 |           |              | code:0
10:09:26.705890 run-command.c:993            | d3 | main                     | child_exit   |     | 76.106345 | 54.939261 |              | [ch3] pid:12022 code:0
```

We see that it takes 54 until `git prune` prints "total objects: 0". No insight *why* `git gc` started `git prune` in the first place.

Comment: `git prune` is looking for unreachable objects to prune (provided they meet the time given). This is inherently slow, although *several minutes* indicates a very large repo and/or a very busy machine. It's not clear to me why `git gc` is running `git prune` at all here though, giving it an explicit "never". It would also be possible to make `git prune` handle `never` as a special case, but I'm not sure I like that idea as much as having `git gc` be smarter about *not running it* in the first place. :-)

Comment: It's just a Linux kernel repo with a couple of remotes including `-stable` and `-next`.

Comment: "Just" a Linux kernel?  While massive players like Microsoft laugh at the tiny Linux-kernel repository size, that's actually quite large, as Git repositories go.

Comment: @torek And laugh they are: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bharry/the-largest-git-repo-on-the-planet/

Answer (score 1):

Try and activate `GIT_TRACE2=1` before launching the `git remote update command`, to see more about the sequence of commands. (You have also [`GIT_TRACE2_PERF` or `GIT_TRACE2_EVENT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309))

[`git maintenance`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance) (that I [detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64077241/6309)) means at least Git 2.30: see if the issue persists with the latest 2.33.0.2.

---

With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), "[`git maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ed8794ef7ae9f345ab88c6f1ee728e06fc7b8ce4/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance))</sup> scheduler learned to use systemd timers as a possible backend.

That will allow a better control on when that kind of process (`git gc` before, `git maintenance` now) is taking place.

See [commit b681b19](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b681b191f923267aab80ae7f7ab2f85a692e8833), [commit eba1ba9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eba1ba9d32f14dd9c052b1e2eb50e5718421d10e), [commit cb7db5b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cb7db5bbd56f587a35c1861282c46d424fee0b38) (04 Sep 2021) by [Lénaïc Huard (`L3n41c`)](https://github.com/L3n41c).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ed8794e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed8794ef7ae9f345ab88c6f1ee728e06fc7b8ce4), 20 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b681b191f923267aab80ae7f7ab2f85a692e8833): add support for systemd timers on Linux
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Lénaïc Huard</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> The existing mechanism for scheduling background maintenance is done through cron.
> On Linux systems managed by systemd, systemd provides an alternative to schedule recurring tasks: systemd timers.
>
> The main motivations to implement systemd timers in addition to cron are: * cron is optional and Linux systems running systemd might not have it installed. * The execution of `crontab -l` can tell us if cron is installed but not if the daemon is actually running. * With systemd, each service is run in its own cgroup and its logs are tagged by the service inside journald.
> With cron, all scheduled tasks are running in the cron daemon cgroup and all the logs of the user-scheduled tasks are pretended to belong to the system cron service.
> Concretely, a user that doesn't have access to the system logs won't have access to the log of their own tasks scheduled by cron whereas they will have access to the log of their own tasks scheduled by systemd timer.
> Although `cron` attempts to send email, that email may go unseen by the user because these days, local mailboxes are not heavily used anymore.
>
> In order to schedule [`git maintenance`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b681b191f923267aab80ae7f7ab2f85a692e8833/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance))</sup>, we need two unit template files: * ~/.config/systemd/user/git-maintenance@.service to define the command to be started by systemd and * ~/.config/systemd/user/git-maintenance@.timer to define the schedule at which the command should be run.
>
> Those units are templates that are parameterized by the frequency.
>
> Based on those templates, 3 timers are started: * git-maintenance@hourly.timer * git-maintenance@daily.timer * git-maintenance@weekly.timer
>
> The command launched by those three timers are the same as with the other scheduling methods:
>
> /path/to/[`git for-each-repo`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b681b191f923267aab80ae7f7ab2f85a692e8833/Documentation/git-for-each-repo.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-repo))</sup> --exec-path=/path/to --config=maintenance.repo maintenance run --schedule=%i
>
> with the full path for git to ensure that the version of git launched for the scheduled maintenance is the same as the one used to run `maintenance start`.
>
> The timer unit contains `Persistent=true` so that, if the computer is powered down when a maintenance task should run, the task will be run when the computer is back powered on.

`git maintenance` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b681b191f923267aab80ae7f7ab2f85a692e8833/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L182):

> ### `--scheduler=auto|crontab|systemd-timer|launchctl|schtasks`

`git maintenance` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b681b191f923267aab80ae7f7ab2f85a692e8833/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L186-L191):

> Possible values for `<scheduler>` are `auto`, `crontab`
> (POSIX), `systemd-timer` (Linux), `launchctl` (macOS), and
> `schtasks` (Windows).
>
> When `auto` is specified, the
> appropriate platform-specific scheduler is used; on Linux,
> `systemd-timer` is used if available, otherwise
> `crontab`. Default is `auto`.

`git maintenance` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b681b191f923267aab80ae7f7ab2f85a692e8833/Documentation/git-maintenance.txt#L291-L336):

> ### BACKGROUND MAINTENANCE ON LINUX SYSTEMD SYSTEMS
>
> While Linux supports `cron`, depending on the distribution, `cron` may
> be an optional package not necessarily installed. On modern Linux
> distributions, systemd timers are superseding it.
>
> If user systemd timers are available, they will be used as a replacement
> of `cron`.
>
> In this case, `git maintenance start` will create user systemd timer units
> and start the timers. The current list of user-scheduled tasks can be found
> by running `systemctl --user list-timers`. The timers written by `git maintenance start` are similar to this:
>
> ```
> $ systemctl --user list-timers
> NEXT                         LEFT          LAST                         PASSED     UNIT                         ACTIVATES
> Thu 2021-04-29 19:00:00 CEST 42min left    Thu 2021-04-29 18:00:11 CEST 17min ago  git-maintenance@hourly.timer git-maintenance@hourly.service
> Fri 2021-04-30 00:00:00 CEST 5h 42min left Thu 2021-04-29 00:00:11 CEST 18h ago    git-maintenance@daily.timer  git-maintenance@daily.service
> Mon 2021-05-03 00:00:00 CEST 3 days left   Mon 2021-04-26 00:00:11 CEST 3 days ago git-maintenance@weekly.timer git-maintenance@weekly.service
> ```
>
> One timer is registered for each `--schedule=<frequency>` option.
>
> The definition of the systemd units can be inspected in the following files:
>
> ```
> ~/.config/systemd/user/git-maintenance@.timer
> ~/.config/systemd/user/git-maintenance@.service
> ~/.config/systemd/user/timers.target.wants/git-maintenance@hourly.timer
> ~/.config/systemd/user/timers.target.wants/git-maintenance@daily.timer
> ~/.config/systemd/user/timers.target.wants/git-maintenance@weekly.timer
> ```
>
> `git maintenance start` will overwrite these files and start the timer
> again with `systemctl --user`, so any customization should be done by
> creating a drop-in file, i.e. a `.conf` suffixed file in the
> `~/.config/systemd/user/git-maintenance@.service.d` directory.
>
> `git maintenance stop` will stop the user systemd timers and delete
> the above mentioned files.
>
> For more details, see `systemd.timer(5)`.

---

With Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), update `git maintenance` timers implementation based on systemd timers to work with WSL.

See [commit 5e8515e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e8515e8e8d10f882d1e8ffeb34b8348426515ed) (10 Sep 2023) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bd49a29](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd49a2998a87fe911dfa5f6574443968faa5878a), 20 Sep 2023)</sup>

> ### [`maintenance(systemd)`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e8515e8e8d10f882d1e8ffeb34b8348426515ed): support the Windows Subsystem for Linux
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> When running in the **Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)**, it is usually necessary to use the Git Credential Manager for authentication when performing the background fetches.
>
> This requires interoperability between the Windows Subsystem for Linux and the Windows host to work, which uses so-called vsocks, i.e.
> sockets intended for communcations between virtual machines and the host they are running on.
>
> However, when Git is configured to run background maintenance via `systemd`, the address families available to those maintenance processes are restricted, and did not include `AF_VSOCK`.
> This leads to problems e.g. when a background fetch tries to access github.com:
>
> ```
> systemd[437]: Starting Optimize Git repositories data...
> git[747387]: WSL (747387) ERROR: UtilBindVsockAnyPort:285: socket failed 97
> git[747381]: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
> git[747381]: error: failed to prefetch remotes
> git[747381]: error: task 'prefetch' failed
> systemd[437]: git-maintenance@hourly.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
> systemd[437]: git-maintenance@hourly.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
> systemd[437]: Failed to start Optimize Git repositories data.
> ```
>
> Address this (pun intended) by adding the `AF_VSOCK` address family to the allow list.
>
> This fixes [`microsoft/git` issue 604](https://github.com/microsoft/git/issues/604).

Comment: I'm currently at 2.32.0 (openSUSE Tumbleweed).

Comment: @uncleremus OK. I would be curious to know if this persists with 2.33.

Comment: Yes, it still happens with 2.33. I have a `GIT_TRACE2=1` log. Adding a snippet to the question above, but it doesn't provide much insight.

Comment: @uncleremus Not much to see indeed. Would  `GIT_TRACE2_PERF` or `GIT_TRACE2_EVENT` yield anything more?

Comment: The systemd timers suggestion wouldn't help me. Indeed I want `git gc` to run synchronously on the repository at hand. Asynchronous maintenance would just be a workaround for the fact that `gc` / `prune` is so slow.

Comment: @uncleremus Yet said asynchronous maintenance can be set for one repository.